# How to detect file system size limitations of individual files

Tags: c++, filesystems

is there a way to detect the file system size limitations of individual files (e.g. 4gb on fat 32)?

It must work on Windows OS, but better would be a portable solution. Detecting the file system type could be a work around, but I don't know how you can do that either.

Can anybody help me out here?

Thank you in advance
Tobias

Comment: I can certainly think of non-portable ways of querying the *name* of the file system on Windows, but I don't think that properly satisfies your request...

Comment: It would probably solve my problem for now - but it would leave me with an uneasy feeling of having a "ugly" solution for this problem. Still if there's no other way, it can't be helped.

Comment: ...but kudos to you for at least seeking out a better, cleaner option. Many developers wouldn't do the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect the filesystem type on Windows with [GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: ...or through WMI, if so desired. You'll need to hard-code knowledge of generally supported file systems, though (e.g. NTFS, FAT, FAT32, EXFAT, CDFS, UDF, etc.).

Comment: @ruben: Yes but after looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I don't really see a better way. Maybe the IFS kit knows more IOCTL codes that might help though...

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the **total** capacity limitations through [`boost::space()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#space), or directly use POSIX [`fstatvs()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/statvfs.html).

As for limitations on the size of individual files... the only portable answer that springs to mind is ugly brute force try-to-create-larger-and-larger-files-until-failure, expensive as it is (and impossible if capacity is already limited).

Comment: That may provide the amount of free space, but not necessarily any inherent implementation limits of the file-system...

Comment: Quite. I'm a bit confused as to when inherent adressing limitations would be of interest, rather than the capacity, though.

Comment: Consider a file system that has more than 4 GB of free space but still doesn't allow the creation of files larger than 4 GB. This may be important to understand up-front, before you've tried to create any such file...

Comment: OK: size limitations on **individual** files. True, that's  interesting.

Comment: yes, that's exactly the case. You create a file and the user has the option to stop the recording. So you don't know up front how large the user wants it to be. It would be at least nice to stop gracefully before you hit the limit.