# Get maximum file size for specific drive

Tags: winapi, filesystems

Is there some WinAPI way to get maximum file size for specific drive?

For example, I know that in FAT32 maximum file size is 4GB. Should I find out that file system on a drive is FAT32 and then use my previous knowledge about FAT32 or there is a way in Windows to get the max file size directly?

What I already do:

I determine file system type using `GetVolumeInformation` and then use a mapping table that maps file system type to its known maximum file size.

What I want:

I would like to know whether Microsoft has provided a way to get directly the maximum file size in bytes for an arbitrary file system type, even the one that do not exist yet and about which I cannot have knowledge by definition now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect file system size limitations of individual files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340654/how-to-detect-file-system-size-limitations-of-individual-files)

Comment: No, it just repeats the pessimistic scenario from my question. My question is about whether there is a way not to do like in answer to that another question.

Comment: You should list what you have already done, seen and tested in your question so nobody loses time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some WinAPI way to get maximum file size for specific drive?

No.  Microsoft does not provide an API for that particular piece of information.

> Should I find out that file system on a drive is FAT32 and then use my previous knowledge about FAT32

Yes.

> or there is a way in Windows to get the max file size directly?

There is no way provided.

> I determine file system type using GetVolumeInformation and then use a mapping table that maps file system type to its known maximum file size.

That is what you have to do.